# How to place a button at an specific coordinate in an imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have added following image in an `imageview`. This is a jpeg image

[image]

Designer provided me the coordinates of the `dot` in this `imageView`. What i need to do is to add a button over this `dot`.

Is there any way i can achieve this in android.

Comment: You can use `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: What about creating a FrameLayout of size equal to your image. Inside place your ImageView first (match parent size) and then Button. Then simply set margins on Button.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A button might not be best if you just want a specific region of an image to be clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try ConstraintLayout and add guide lines using percentages of the image height or with such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50121653" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use setX and setY on the button to put it where you want

```
button.setX(dotX);
button.setY(dotY);
```

But to center the button on the dot

```
button.setX(dotX - buttonWidth/2);
button.setY(dotY - buttonHeight/2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You get your view with the help of constraint layout i did something same just check this code....

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".5">

    <me.tankery.lib.circularseekbar.CircularSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/circularSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:cs_circle_color="#0000ff"
        app:cs_circle_progress_color="#ff0000"
        app:cs_circle_stroke_width="4dp"
        app:cs_pointer_color="#ff0000"
        app:cs_pointer_stroke_width="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:src="@drawable/play"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

It gives me the view like button in middle of the seekbar

NOTE: PLease use drag and drop it gives the perfect implementation

Answer (score 1):

You should use RelativeLayout instead

EXAMPLE:

Suppose you want a ImageView of size 50x60 on your screen at postion (70x80)

// RelativeLayout. though you can use xml RelativeLayout here too by `findViewById()`

```
 RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        // ImageView
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

        // Setting layout params to our RelativeLayout
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 60);





// Setting position of our ImageView
        layoutParams.leftMargin = 70;
        layoutParams.topMargin = 80;

        // Finally Adding the imageView to RelativeLayout and its position
        relativeLayout.addView(imageView, layoutParams);
```